# Richfaces 3.1.6 fail to work on IE 10

Tags: richfaces

I'm getting the following javascript error on all a4j:commandlink on our site.  This error only occurred on IE 10.  No problem with IE 8 / 9.

Message: Object doesn't support property or method 'setProperty'
Line: 6
Char: 148
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost.com:9082/a4j_3_1_6.GAorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript.jsf

I can't be sure but the following appears to be the statement in error:
oDoc.setProperty("SelectionLanguage","XPath")

and oDoc appears to be created thru this statemetn: oDoc=new ActiveXObject(idList[i]

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: First off all, you should update your richfaces at least to the version 3.3.3.Final which is the latest version for RF 3.x. There are know bugs with the version 3.x of richfaces regarding IE you can either input a hack into your code simulating IE 8/9 or try to fix yourself the problem downloading richfaces code (which will be painfull, I did that for an error that I found on the last version also for IE)

Comment: I'm using JSF 1.1.  I think 3.1.6 is the latest for JSF 1.1.  I'm working on moving to JSF2.0 and probably won't be in production until mid next year.  For this migration, I'm also getting rid of richfaces, replacing all ajax functions with f:ajax.  Painful process but I think it is necessary becuase richfaces has been giving problem every time a new version of IE comes out, which management keeps thinking if moving to JSF frame work is a good idea in the first place.

Comment: The latest version of the richfaces for JSF 1.1 is 3.3.3.Final which is the one I use ion the project I'm working now. And I would rather use Primefaces (I think it is better, JSF 2 is a +). And yes I agree with you, Richfaces is painfull. But the latest version has a lot of bugs fixed since this one you are using. Try to update and test your issue, maybe it is already fixed.

Comment: I can't change it to Primefaces because it is a huge project and the company doesnt want to pay the time for the convertion, at least not right now.

Comment: to be fair, most of the richfaces problem seems to be occurring on third party codes that it is using.  Mostly in Sarissa or jQuery.

Comment: Yes, that it is true. But also IE is the bad guy, that's because microsoft did not follow the w3c pattern for the scripting, then every script framework has to test if it is running on it (IE but check just browser not the version). From IE version 9 Microsoft start to follow w3c pattern then every framework that test just the browser (not the version) has broken code because the code runs to the old versions of IE.

Answer (score 2):

Below is what I did to resolve this issue:

1) Download sarissa-full-0.9.9.6.zip from http://sourceforge.net/projects/sarissa/

2) Find the sarissa.js file in sarissa-full-0.9.9.6.zip and open it with wordpad.

3) Find the AJAX.js file in richfaces-impl-3.1.6.GA.jar and open it with wordpad.

4) Within AJAX.js, there is a section of code that is really a copy of old version of sarissa.js.  This section of code starts and ends like below:

/**
 * ====================================================================
 * About
 * ====================================================================
 * Sarissa is an ECMAScript library acting as a cross-browser wrapper for native XML APIs.
 * The library supports Gecko based browsers like Mozilla and Firefox,
 * Internet Explorer (5.5+ with MSXML3.0+), Konqueror, Safari and a little of Opera
 * @version ${project.version}
 * @author: Manos Batsis, mailto: mbatsis at users full stop sourceforge full stop net

. . . .
. . . . 
. . . .

//   EOF

5) Replace this entire section of sarissa code in AJAX.js with the codes in sarissa.js (see #2).

6) Now search for all texts in AJAX.js that start with _SARISSA.  Append Sarissa. in front of the text if it does not have one.  For example: if(_SARISSA_IS_IE){  should be changed to if(Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE){

7) Now replace below (see http://sourceforge.net/p/sarissa/bugs/62/):

Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE9 = Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 9") > -1;

with

Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE9 = Sarissa._SARISSA_IS_IE && (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 9") > -1 || navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie 10") > -1 || document.documentMode >= 9);

8) Save and replace this newly updated AJAX.js into richfaces-impl-3.1.6.GA.jar.

9) Now you are ready to test it out.  Note: For some odd reason, for IE10 to take the newly updated AJAX.js, I've to access the page and do a save as to save the enire html to my local.  Once I did that the new AJAX.js starts to take effect.  There is probably other way to refresh the cache but this is the one that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I also had to delete the following row in the Ajax.js:

LOG.debug("Hidden JSF state fields: "+idsSpan);